# python sqlite get hebrew string from user and insert to DB

Tags: python, sqlite, hebrew

When I try to get an Hebrew input and insert it to the DB I see nothing, but if the variable `LightRemark` already has a Hebrew string, I see it in the DB.

What could be the problem?

```
con = lite.connect('SMART-BUS.sqlite')
cur = con.cursor()  
LightRemark = raw_input("Light Remark? ")
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO LightInZone(LightRemark)
              VALUES(?)''', (LightRemark))
con.commit()
```

As you can see in the code:

1. Connects to the DB
2. Gets input from the user
3. Executes the SQL statement
4. Commits it

The Hebrew string is not showing in DB.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Did you make sure you support unicode in both DB and your program?
Try adding a "u" before the sql statement:
`u'''INSERT INTO...'''`

Comment: Also, try running `LightRemark = raw_input().decode('utf-8')`
Just to make sure your input gets correctly stored and can be deciphered correctly

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3?

Comment: @immortal, once i try to add the decode func i get:
'    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 0: invalid start byte'

Comment: @HåkenLid, I use python 2

Comment: Since you are working with hebrew text, python 3 would make your life easier, since all strings are unicode by default. If you want to handle unicode text in python 2, you should read up on text encodings.

Comment: @BarPerez This will be a good time to ask: Python version (full) and OS?
Because the code above worked for me...
There's also a question of terminal used..?

Comment: @HåkenLid works! thanks!

Comment: @immortal the code itself works but on 2.7 it won't pass unicode string to the DB, on 3.6 it those work

Comment: @BarPerez This might be a matter of the encoding of your terminal and how Python captures the string with raw_input.
Try using `sys.stdin.encoding` to figure out which encoding is passed by your terminal. Then try decoding the received string using the terminal encoding, and then, again, encoding the resulting string into utf-8.